# JPA with EJB with separated DAO and Service Layers

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

This is more an architecture problem I currently have. I need help regarding the best practices of integrating EJB and JPA on a project. I want to have EJBs which will do the job of the service layer, containing the business logic of my application. Right under that, I would like to have a DAO layer which my EJBs will have a handle using a DAO factory to separate those two layers as much as possible. Knowing that, I obviously cannot make my DAO as EJBs also because I don't want them injected automatically, as I want them to be created through the factory. That leads me to create the entitymanager manually using

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PortalEJB").createEntityManager();
```

Now... this call is located in my abstract JPA DAO:

```
public abstract class JPADataAccessorObject<K, E> implements DataAccessorObject<K, E> {
    protected Class<E> entityClass;

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    protected JPADataAccessorObject(Class<E> pEntityClass) {
        this.entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PortalEJB").createEntityManager();
        this.entityClass = pEntityClass;
    }

    /* Other DAO functions (update, delete, create) */
}
```

I think this is bad, isn't it? All my concrete extents of this class will have a brand new copy of the persistence context and I will get strange behaviour. Moreover, when I do that, I **think** I have to manage the transactions myself in the service layer. I was about to create Aspects for that, something like:

- Create transaction before any service layer's function/procedure
- (rollback the transaction if any exception occurs)
- Commit the transaction after any service layer's function/procedure

So here are my questions:

- How should I manage the EntityManager?
- Should I have some kind of JPA utility class which will manage it to have one copy protected from multithreading?
- If I'm making a horrible mistake, please provide best practices.

Comment: Which version of Java EE?

Comment: I'm using EJB 3.1, Java 1.6, JPA 2.0 (EclipseLink) on GlassFish 3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen the post of Adam Bien [JPA/EJB3 KILLED THE DAO](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao) and [DAOS AREN'T DEAD - BUT THEY EITHER COLLAPSED OR DISAPPEARED](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/daos_aren_t_dead_but)?

In another hand, you can consider an abstract class for the service layer:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<E extends Serializable, 
                                     PK extends Serializable> {

    private final transient Class<E> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(final Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(final E entity) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public final E find(final PK id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    // Other common operations

}
```

And a particular *service*:

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User, String> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UserFacade() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    // Other methods of this service

}
```

See more in [*Java EE 6/7: The Lean Parts*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvtuFLz2prk) from JavaOne 2012 in San Francisco.

Comment: In your example, your service layer depends on JPA, which is, in my opinion, a bad thing. Suppose you have users coming from an an old mainframe which will "dump" them on a FTP server. With the DAO factory, you could have an FTPUserDAO and JPAUserDAO that would be extents of UserDAO. The way you proposed, you would have to have a completely new set of service layer for FTP. Now, what if you have a really complex business algorithm on your users?

Comment: There is no problem. You can create a particular factory for your legacy system and inject it with CDI.

Comment: I don't agree with that. Have DAO and Services separated is, in my humble opinion, a safer to go. Your last link though, at the beginning of the video, the guy searches for JSF JPA Tutorial and have a good tutorial of exactly what I need!!! http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JSF_Tutorial

Comment: 99 percent business logic and 1 percent infrastructure!

Comment: You made me realize one thing that will probably help me in my future life: The best solution is not always the "by the book" solution. I wanted to be as "perfect" as possible, but that makes the code too complex for its purpose. Thank you very much ;)